# Extending custom type where associated type is equal to Void

Tags: swift, generics, swift3, protocols, protocol-extension

I'm in a situation where I have a custom type that contains an `associatedtype`. In the case where this is equal to `Void`, I would like to have some default behaviour (to make the call-site more convenient). I tried to boil the example down to:

```
protocol FooType {
    associatedtype T: Any
    var bar: (String) -> T { get }
}

struct Foo<T>: FooType {
    let bar: (String) -> T
}

extension Foo where T == Void { // Compile error: "Same-type requirement makes generic parameter 'T' non-generic".
    init() {
        self.bar = { _ in return }
    }
}
```

The idea is that, in the cases where the generic type is `Void`, it doesn't make sense (in my scenario) to pass in a function (named `bar` in the example). Therefore, I just want a default implementation for this function in this specific context.

When trying to do the above I get the `Same-type requirement makes generic parameter 'T' non-generic` which sounds very similar to what happens when one tries to restrict e.g. the `Array` type when containing specific types. A workaround for this is to introduce a protocol, but I cannot do that for `Void`. Is it possible to do what I want or is this currently a limitation in Swift 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Swift 3.1, the code posted in the question now works. That is, the following now works as wanted:

```
protocol FooType {
    associatedtype T: Any
    var bar: (String) -> T { get }
}

struct Foo<T>: FooType {
    let bar: (String) -> T
}

extension Foo where T == Void { 
    init() {
        self.bar = { _ in return }
    }
}

let foo = Foo<String>(bar: { (t: String) in return "" })
let zoo = Foo<Void>()
```